# An empty window pops up and steals focus each time an int is assigned using qrand() in Qt

Tags: qt, random

I'm having a strange problem in a game I'm building in Qt where each time I generate I call qrand() (or rand(), I tried both), a separate tiny window pops up and steals focus from my game. I want to 'roll' a pair of dice every 2 seconds so I'm generating a number between 1 and 12. I'm using a QTimer object in a `GameBoard` custom widget constructor to call the public slot `updateDice()` that resets a private variable to a random number.

```
void GameBord::updateDice(){
    dice_int = qrand()%12 +1;
    repaint();
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    return;
}
```

and in my repaint()

```
...
dice_roll->clear();
dice_roll->setText(QString::number(dice_int));
...
```

where `dice_roll` is the label that displays what number the roll was for the player.

With the debugger I found that every time `dice_int` is assigned the window pops up. The weirdest part to me is that I have other random numbers generated and they don't cause this problem.

I know you can `setAttribute` so that the window comes up without activating, but I don't know where the window is coming from.

And if there is no solution to this problem, is there a way to set Focus on a widget so that it never changes? I tried `Qt::StrongFocus` but that doesn't help.

I'd be happy to post more code if you want it, and thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you certain `rand()` and `qrand()` are causing the window to appear?  In other words, if you put a breakpoint on the line after, do you see the window when the breakpoint is hit?

Comment: Why do you call `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` in QTimer shot? also `dice_roll->clear();` seems to be redundant.

Comment: @MrEricSirSorry, my mistake, the problem is every time that `dice_int` is assigned. I got the two confused because I was assigning that variable with `rand()`. This is a very important variable for game play, so I'm really hoping to figure this out.